# How to create an observable function that consumes anther observable function

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I need to cache lookup in an angular service,
i will get countries list from a web api and store it in variable `Countries` by `getCountries`,
knowing that sometimes i need list `Countries` to be sent back to the caller

Also i need to filter countries by `id` so I am using the  `getCountryByID`

how i can return observable in `getCountries` and `getCountryByID`

in the below code the returning value is the uninitialized list and when the next is triggered, the caller do not receive the new value

```
Countries: LookupModel[];

 getCountries(): Observable<LookupModel[]> {
    if (!this.Countries || this.Countries.length == 0) {
         this._lookupsClient.lookupsAll('Countries')
          .subscribe(
                    result => {
                    this.Countries = result;
                    return Observable.of(this.Countries);
                              },
                     error => {
                                return <Observable<LookupModel[]>><any>Observable.throw(error);
                               });
            }
  //this is returning only
return Observable.of<LookupModel[]>(this.Countries);
  }

getCountryByID(Id: string): Observable<LookupModel> {

this.getCountries().subscribe(next => {

  let temp = next.filter(y => y.value == Id);
  if (temp && temp.length > 0) {
    return temp[0];
  }
  else { return Observable.of(new LookupModel({ name: Id })); }
}
);

//this is returning only
return Observable.of(new LookupModel({ name: Id }));


 }
```

Comment: Best combo that can work it out is BehaviorSubject.

Comment: try this code , but not guarantee.
`this.getCountries().pipe(filter(ele => ele.id)). subscribe(...)`

Comment: Why are you returning observable of this.nationalities?

`//this is returning only
return Observable.of<LookupModel[]>(this.nationalities);`

Comment: change to Countries